# splitting mysql column into two columns with delimiter

Tags: mysql

I have a DB where one column is a person's job information in the form of: "name of employer/job title" e.g. "Harvard University/Professor"  I want to split this into two columns  an employer column and a title column.

Is there a quick way to do this in MySQL or do I need to write a script to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence below answers your question, but also provides some basic direction you can try.  I personally would do it in PHP (or whatever server-side you are working with).

The following is copied from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

> MySQL does not include a function to split a delimited string.
>   Although separated data would normally be split into separate fields
>   within a relation data, spliting such can be useful either during
>   initial data load/validation or where such data is held in a text
>   field.
>
> The following formula can be used to extract the Nth item in a
>   delimited list, in this case the 3rd item "ccccc" in the example comma
>   separated list.
>
> select replace(substring(substring_index('aaa,bbbb,ccccc', ',', 3),
>   length(substring_index('aaa,bbbb,ccccc', ',', 3 - 1)) + 1), ',', '')
>   ITEM3
>
> The above formula does not need the first item to be handled as a
>   special case and returns empty strings correctly when the item count
>   is less than the position requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ALTER TABLE` statement to add this two column -> populate data from this column to the newly created columns -> drop the old "name of employer/job title" column.

HINT: You can use `substring_index` finction of mysql to split out the data from old column

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    replace(substring(substring_index('Harvard University/Professor', '/', 2),
            length(substring_index('Harvard University/Professor', '/', 2 - 1)) + 1),
            '/',
   '')
```

(idea taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html )